Convert XML file into dictionary, with ElementTree
I have an XML configuration file used by legacy software, which I cannot change or format. The goal is to use Python 3.9 and transform the XML file into a dictionary, using only xml.etree.ElementTree library.
I was originally looking at this reply, which produces almost the expected results.
Scenario.xml file contents:
<Scenario Name="{{ env_name }}">
    <Gateways>
        <Alpha Host="{{ host.alpha_name }}" Order="1">
           <Config>{{ CONFIG_DIR }}/alpha.xml</Config>
           <Arguments>-t1 -t2</Arguments>
        </Alpha>
        <Beta Host="{{ host.beta_name }}" Order="2">
           <Config>{{ CONFIG_DIR }}/beta.xml</Config>
           <Arguments>-t1</Arguments>
        </Beta>
        <Gamma Host="{{ host.gamma_name }}" Order="3">
           <Config>{{ CONFIG_DIR }}/gamma.xml</Config>
           <Arguments>-t2</Arguments>
           <!--<Data Count="58" />-->
        </Gamma>
    </Gateways>
</Scenario>

Python code to convert XML file to dictionary:
from pprint import pprint
from xml.etree import ElementTree


def format_xml_to_dictionary(element: ElementTree.Element):
    '''
    Format xml to dictionary

    :param element: Tree element
    :return: Dictionary formatted result
    '''
    try:
        return {
            **element.attrib,
            '#text': element.text.strip(),
            **{i.tag: format_xml_to_dictionary(i) for i in element}
        }
    except ElementTree.ParseError as e:
        raise e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = ElementTree.parse('Scenario.xml').getroot()
    scenario = format_xml_to_dictionary(tree)
    pprint(scenario)

Functional code output with <!--<Data Count="58" />--> commented:
$ python test.py
{'#text': '',
 'Gateways': {'#text': '',
              'Alpha': {'#text': '',
                        'Arguments': {'#text': '-t1 -t2'},
                        'Config': {'#text': '{{ CONFIG_DIR }}/alpha.xml'},
                        'Host': '{{ host.alpha_name }}',
                        'Order': '1'},
              'Beta': {'#text': '',
                       'Arguments': {'#text': '-t1'},
                       'Config': {'#text': '{{ CONFIG_DIR }}/beta.xml'},
                       'Host': '{{ host.beta_name }}',
                       'Order': '2'},
              'Gamma': {'#text': '',
                        'Arguments': {'#text': '-t2'},
                        'Config': {'#text': '{{ CONFIG_DIR }}/gamma.xml'},
                        'Host': '{{ host.gamma_name }}',
                        'Order': '3'}},
 'Name': '{{ env_name }}'}

I'm trying to address two issues:

Scenario is missing from dictionary keys, because root node is already the Scenario tag, I'm not sure what I need to do, in order to make it part of dictionary
If I uncomment <Data Count="58" />, I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

I'm not sure what type of if/else condition I need to implement, I tried something like that, but it is setting all #text values to '' instead of stripping them:
'#text': element.text.strip() if isinstance(
    element.text, ElementTree.Element
) else '',


Where should Scenario be in the desired results?

What should the result be if you have multiple nodes with the same name? Dictionary keys have to be unique.

Use an if statement for the text. if element.text: result['#text'] = element.text.strip()

tree.tag should contain Scenario. I think you can use this outside the recursion to create the top-level dictionary.

To get Scenario into the result, use tree.tag as the key in the outermost dictionary when calling the function.
To handle nodes with no text, add the #text key to the dictionary in a separate statement, so it can be conditional.
def format_xml_to_dictionary(element: ElementTree.Element):
    '''
    Format xml to dictionary

    :param element: Tree element
    :return: Dictionary formatted result
    '''
    try:
        result = {
            **element.attrib,
            **{i.tag: format_xml_to_dictionary(i) for i in element}
        }
        if element.text:
            result['#text'] = element.text.strip()
        return result
    except ElementTree.ParseError as e:
        raise e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = ElementTree.parse('Scenario.xml').getroot()
    scenario = {
        tree.tag: format_xml_to_dictionary(tree)
    }
    pprint(scenario)

